# How to Design the Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, classification

I was trying to make a deep learning prediction model for predicting whether a person is a CKD patient or not. Can you please tell me? How can I design a neural network for it? How many neurons should I add in each layer? Or is there any other method in Keras to do so? The dataset link: https://github.com/Samar-080301/Python_Project/blob/master/ckd_full.csv

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\samar\OneDrive\desktop\projects\Chronic_Kidney_Disease')
os.getcwd()
x=pd.read_csv('ckd_full.csv')
y=x[['class']]
y['class']=y['class'].replace(to_replace=(r'ckd',r'notckd'), value=(1,0))
x=x.drop(columns=['class'])
x['rbc']=x['rbc'].replace(to_replace=(r'normal',r'abnormal'), value=(1,0))
x['pcc']=x['pcc'].replace(to_replace=(r'present',r'notpresent'), value=(1,0))
x['ba']=x['ba'].replace(to_replace=(r'present',r'notpresent'), value=(1,0))
x['pc']=x['pc'].replace(to_replace=(r'normal',r'abnormal'), value=(1,0))
x['htn']=x['htn'].replace(to_replace=(r'yes',r'no'), value=(1,0))
x['dm']=x['dm'].replace(to_replace=(r'yes',r'no'), value=(1,0))
x['cad']=x['cad'].replace(to_replace=(r'yes',r'no'), value=(1,0))
x['pe']=x['pe'].replace(to_replace=(r'yes',r'no'), value=(1,0))
x['ane']=x['ane'].replace(to_replace=(r'yes',r'no'), value=(1,0))
x['appet']=x['appet'].replace(to_replace=(r'good',r'poor'), value=(1,0))
x[x=="?"]=np.nan
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.01)
#begin the model
model=keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128,input_dim = 24, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu)) # adding a layer with 128 nodes and relu activaation function
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu)) # adding a layer with 128 nodes and relu activaation function
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu)) # adding a layer with 128 nodes and relu activaation function
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu)) # adding a layer with 128 nodes and relu activaation function 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu)) # adding a layer with 128 nodes and relu activaation function
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation=tf.nn.softmax)) # adding a layer with 2 nodes and softmax activaation function
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) # specifiying hyperparameters
model.fit(xtrain,ytrain,epochs=5) # load the model
model.save('Nephrologist') # save the model with a unique name
myModel=tf.keras.models.load_model('Nephrologist')  # make an object of the model
prediction=myModel.predict((xtest))



     C:\Users\samar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:12: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
    A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
    Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
    
    See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
      if sys.path[0] == '':
Epoch 1/5
396/396 [==============================] - 0s 969us/sample - loss: nan - acc: 0.3561
Epoch 2/5
396/396 [==============================] - 0s 343us/sample - loss: nan - acc: 0.3763
Epoch 3/5
396/396 [==============================] - 0s 323us/sample - loss: nan - acc: 0.3763
Epoch 4/5
396/396 [==============================] - 0s 283us/sample - loss: nan - acc: 0.3763
Epoch 5/5
396/396 [==============================] - 0s 303us/sample - loss: nan - acc: 0.3763
```

Comment: Please see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the structure that I achieved 100% test accuracy with:

```
model=keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(200,input_dim = 24, activation=tf.nn.tanh))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) # specifiying hyperparameters

xtrain_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(xtrain, dtype=tf.float32)
ytrain_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(ytrain, dtype=tf.float32)
model.fit(xtrain_tensor , ytrain_tensor , epochs=500, batch_size=128, validation_split = 0.15, shuffle=True, verbose=2) # load the model
results = model.evaluate(xtest, ytest, batch_size=128)
```

Output:

```
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.2560 - accuracy: 0.9412 - val_loss: 0.2227 - val_accuracy: 0.9815
Epoch 500/500
3/3 - 0s - loss: 0.2225 - accuracy: 0.9673 - val_loss: 0.2224 - val_accuracy: 0.9815
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 0s/step - loss: 0.1871 - accuracy: 1.0000
```

The last line represents the evaluation of the model on the test dataset. Seems like it generalized well :)

------------------------------------------------- Original answer below ---------------------------------------------------
I would go with a logistic regression model first in order to see if there is any predictive value to your dataset.

```
model=keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,input_dim = 24, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) # specifiying hyperparameters
model.fit(xtrain,ytrain,epochs=100) # Might require more or less epoches. It depends on the amount of noise in your dataset.
```

If you see you receive an accuracy score that satisfies you, I would give it a try and add 1 or 2 more dense hidden layers with between 10 to 40 nodes.
It's important to mention that my advice is solely based on my experience.

I HIGHLY(!!!!) recommend transforming the y_label into a binary value when 1 represents the positive class (a record is a record of a CKD patient) and 0 represents the negative class.
Let me know if it works, and if it doesn't I'll also try to play with your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! the label is already quantified as 1 & 0, I tried:- 
model=keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128,input_dim = 24, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

Comment: But the loss was NaN!

Comment: I also tried                                                                                                                    bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=bce, metrics=['accuracy'])'                                      but this time it said  "A target array with shape (396, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 2) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output."

Comment: If you changed your target label to a single variable, you should change your output node shape to be 1 instead of 2 as you are classifying the result of a single variable (whether it's 0 or 1)

Comment: Do NaN values create problems in Keras?

Comment: Yeah. As far as it comes with most sort of classification problems, I'd recommend to first try to convert all NaNs to the mean value of that variable. especially if you are dealing with normal distributions. It is important to mention that in some cases defining the mean value as the default value for NaNs may not be the optimal solution, yet it is usually a good starting point. If my answers help you please feel free to upvote my original answer and accept it as the correct solution for your problem. I'll be happy to help you further if you need anything mate!

Comment: Please upvote my question, because my lower rating is preventing me from upvoting you!

Comment: d=['age', 'bp', 'sg','al', 'su', 'rbc', 'pc', 'pcc', 'ba', 'bgr', 'bu', 'sc', 'sod', 'pot', 'hemo', 'pcv', 'wbcc', 'rbcc', 'htn', 'dm','cad', 'appet', 'pe', 'ane']
for i in d:
  x[i] = x[i].astype(float)  
  medi=x[i].median()
  x[i].fillna(medi)  
print(x.head(20))

Comment: df1.fillna(value = df1.mean(), inplace=True)                      Try using this single line of code. replace df1 with the name of your dataset. You can, of course, pick the median value instead of the mean value.    You can also use these line of code to make sure your datatype is actually a NaN and not a string: df1.replace({'NaN': np.nan})  #(The first argument can be anything you used to symbolize null values, not necessarily 'NaN')

Comment: The data is absolutely solved, now you just guide me how to design the model☺️☺️

Comment: Contact me on mail: Mykoryto93@gmail.com (By the way, I upvoted your topic as requested :])

Comment: Brother, did you found any solution?

Comment: Yeah, check your mail. I'll post the solution here as well for others to have as well!

Answer (score 1):

apparently you seem to have problem with your data pre-processing
you can use

```
df.fillna('ffill')
```

and also you can use feature columns to do those long tasks example:

```
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['columns','which have','categorical data','like sex']
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['columns which have','numeric data']
feature_column =[]
for items in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
    feature_column.append( tf.feature_clolumns.categorical_columns_with_vocavulary_list(items, df[items].unique()))

for items in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
    feature_column.append( tf.feature_clolumns.numeric_columns(items, df[items].unique()))
```

now you can use these feature columns to make a prediction for your model which will be more accurate more can be done in data preprocessing here is the official documentation to help you more : [tensorflow Documentation on feature columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns)